# Laravel / Docker / Sail project stored on github: unsuccesful at cloning to a different machine

Tags: php, docker, github, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I created a project on my desktop with laravel and sail / docker.  Been working on it for some time.  I posted my project files to my github repository.  I should have used the docker repository, I realize, but I did not set that up before I left.  So I am trying to clone the github repository on my laptop.

I then follow the directions on **laravel.com** specified at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sharing-your-site to attempt to clone my project stored on github.  The instructions offer the following:

### Installing Composer Dependencies For Existing Applications

*If you are developing an application with a team, you may not be the one that initially creates the Laravel application. Therefore, none of the application's Composer dependencies, including Sail, will be installed after you clone the application's repository to your local computer.*

*You may install the application's dependencies by navigating to the application's directory and executing the following command. This command uses a small Docker container containing PHP and Composer to install the application's dependencies:*

> docker run --rm \
> -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
> -v $(pwd):/opt \
> -w /opt \
> laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
> composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

When I run this, I get multiple errors.

> In fortify.php line 135:
> Call to undefined method Laravel\Fortify\Features::termsAndPrivacyPolicy()

and it gives the following error 3 or 4 times, trying with different pid's.  starting in the 20's and ending with the following pid.

> 2021-06-09 21:45:53,206 INFO exited: php (exit status 1; not expected)
> 2021-06-09 21:45:56,213 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 41

The last error it gives is:

> 2021-06-09 21:45:56,453 INFO exited: php (exit status 1; not expected)
> 2021-06-09 21:45:57,433 INFO gave up: php entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

All of the containers are running with green indicators in the docker dashboard after I issue the sail up command in the project directory.

redis_1 Port:6379 | meilisearch Port:7700 | selenium | mailhog Port:1025 | mysql Port: 3306 | laravel.test Port:80

So the order I did this was opened php storm.  create project from VCS.  Choose github and the appropriate repository, click clone.  Then I ran the docker run command that I mention above.

When I first began, laravel.test would not load because nginx was running on port 80, so I stopped nginx, and everythign loaded.

However localhost:80 does not render.

I read where the version of PHP might create a problem.  sail php --version returns the following though:

> PHP 8.0.7 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2021 21:26:10) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.0.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.0.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Does anyone have any thoughts?  thx.

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer to your problem? I am also looking for a good way to develop with laravel sail with my team but I am not sure how to do that. The docker --rm ... command gives error if I execute it.

Comment: unfortunately, I have not.  I will let you know if i do.

Comment: Make sure you run the docker run --rm command from your linux env inside the project root folder.

Comment: I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

How i did it from kalilinux  cloned repo from github  hope it helps
[Ref Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects)

```
sudo docker run --rm \
-u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
-v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
-w /var/www/html \
laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```